# I have to find $I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(1-2a \cos x+a^2)\, dx$

Tags: calculus

I have to find 
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(1-2a \cos x+a^2)\,dx$$ 
Can someone help me to solve it?

Comment: Take a look at the third example [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that it might be interesting to present a way forward that exploits [Gauss' Mean Value Theorem](https://dyinglovegrape.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/gauss-mean-value-theorem-and-the-maximum-modulus-theorem/).

To proceed, we write the integral of interest as

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi \log(1-2a\cos(x)+a^2)\,dx&=\frac12 \int_{-\pi}^\pi \log(1-2a\cos(x)+a^2)\,dx\\\\
&= \int_{-\pi}^\pi \log|1-ae^{i\theta}|\,d\theta \tag 1\\\\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \log|1+ae^{i\theta}|\,d\theta \tag 2\\\\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \log|1-ae^{i\theta}|\,d\theta \tag 3
\end{align}$$

where in going from $(1)$ to $(2)$ we enforced the substitution $\theta\to \theta -\pi$ and in arriving at $(3)$ we exploited the $2\pi$-periodicity of the integrand.  Therefore, we may assume without loss of generality that $a>0$

---

Now, for $0<a<1$, Gauss' Mean Value Theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \log(1+ae^{i\theta})\,d\theta&=\log(1) \tag 4\\\\
&=0 
\end{align}$$

since $\log(1+z)$ is analytic in and on the disk of radius $a<1$ with center at the origin.

We can write the integrand on the left-hand side of $(4)$ as

$$\log(1+ae^{i\theta})=\log|1+ae^{i\theta}|+i\arg(1+ae^{i\theta}) \tag 5$$

Therefore, integrating $(5)$ reveals

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \log(1+ae^{i\theta})\,d\theta=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \log|1+ae^{i\theta}|\,d\theta+i\int_{0}^{2\pi} \arg(1+ae^{i\theta})\,d\theta $$

whence we conclude from $(2)$ that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi \log(1-2a\cos(x)+a^2)\,dx&=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \log|1+ae^{i\theta}|\,d\theta\\\\
&=\text{Re}\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\log(1+ae^{i\theta})\,d\theta\right)\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

---

> For $a>1$, we simply write
>
> $$\int_0^{2\pi} \log(1+ae^{i\theta})\,d\theta=2\pi \log(a)+\int_0^{2\pi}\log\left(\frac1a +e^{i\theta}\right)\,d\theta \tag 6$$
>
> Applying Gauss' Mean Value Theorem to the integral on the right-hand side of $(6)$, we obtain for $a>1$
>
> $$\int_0^\pi \log(1-2a\cos(x)+a^2)\,dx=2\pi \log(a)$$

Answer (score 0):

We have:
$$ 1-2a\cos x+a^2 = (1-a e^{ix})(1-a e^{-ix})\tag{1}$$
and for every $a$ such that $|a|<1$ we have:
$$ \log\left(1-a e^{ix}\right) = -\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{a^n e^{inx}}{n}\tag{2} $$
so that:

> $$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \log(1-2a\cos x+a^2)\,dx = -\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{a^n}{n}\int_{0}^{\pi}2\cos(nx)\,dx =\color{red}{\large 0}.\tag{3}$$

Thanks to @ddsLeonardo, [this page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) deals with the complementary case $|\alpha|>1$ through differentiation under the integral sign (aka [Feynman's trick](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Feynman.pdf)).

Comment: It is "ln". It is not "log"

Comment: @Tuanlee: they are the same thing, at least to me: $$\log = \log_e = \ln$$

Comment: And anyway, it does not make any difference. The answer is zero for any logarithm.

Comment: According to the link I posted as a comment to the question, the answer is not always zero.

Comment: @ddsLeonardo: I wrote $|\alpha|<1$ and your link is dealing with the complementary case.

Comment: Indeed. I apologize for not noticing it.

Comment: @Tuanlee: you're welcome.